# Stop playing music (rev slider) when user opens new tab

Tags: pages, javascript

i have a simple yet tricky question.

I have a few empty wordpress pages with only a Revolution Slider in each of them. Each Slider has an audio player layer that automatically plays when a user opens the page.

Inside the last slide of the main page i have 5 links to 5 different pages each one with a different slider and with different music.

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to stop the music inside The main revolution slider when a new tab with new music is opened.

I don't know if this is possible at all, but maybe there's some javaScript i can use to let it work.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Sure, if you are in tab A with music playing and you click something in tab A which opens a new tab and that's when you want to stop the music you should be able to find a way with javascript to do what you want. You need to: 1) find how to capture the click event in tab A so you can make something happen then, 2) find out if the music player has a javascript call which can stop the music playing  - it probably does, see if you can find its docs or examples on how to control it with javascript.

Comment: Yeah that's what i thought. I asked Rev Slider support for some help on doing it. Thank you!